# Swift 4 Conversion error - Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' has no member 'foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, nsattributedstringkey

I converted my code from Swift 3 to Swift 4 but getting this error:

> Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' has no member 'foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey'

My code is:

```
let labelText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.productDetailsInfo?.productAttributes?[indexPath.row].Name as String?)!)
labelText.append(NSAttributedString(string:"*"))
let selectedRange = NSMakeRange(labelText.length - 1, 1);
labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: selectedRange)
labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: selectedRange)
```

Comment: Remove that line `labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: selectedRange)`, redo it manually and let the autocompletion help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line

```
  labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: selectedRange)
```

with

```
  labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: selectedRange)
```

Also you can use `addAttributes`  method to set more than 1 attribute at a time for a range

```
  labelText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.red,NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor:UIColor.blue], range: selectedRange)
```

Comment: Value of type 'String' has no member 'addAttribute'

Answer (score 1):

There is such kind of property `foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey`listed in [NSAttributedString.Key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey)

Use [foregroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/1533563-foregroundcolor) directly with `NSAttributedString.Key`

Replace `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` with `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` in your code.

Try this:

```
let labelText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.productDetailsInfo?.productAttributes?[indexPath.row].Name as String?)!)
labelText.append(NSAttributedString(string:"*"))
let selectedRange = NSMakeRange(labelText.length - 1, 1);


// Remove foregroundColorNSAttributedStringKey
// Swift 4.1
labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: selectedRange)
labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: selectedRange)


// Swift 4.2
labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: selectedRange)
labelText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: selectedRange)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 to set foreground color attribute:

```
[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```